# How do you create an installer for Azure Web Apps / Azure Websites

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am a software vendor with a .net web solution that I want customers to be able to easily install / deploy into Azure Web Web Apps / Azure Websites along with a Sql Azure backend. I can't find any installer tool that supports this scenario. I have also looked into the Azure Marketplace but it seems the only option there is to create VM images. I want my customer's to avoid having to deploy to an manage VMs and adopt the IaaS model. Instead they should be able to install to Azure Web Apps with a package that copies all the web solution files and installs and connects the Azure Sql. Is this possible or will I have to manually deploy and configure Azure solution for each customer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the VS Marketplace to do the deployment.  What you need is to create an ARM template.  There is a huge number of samples here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates - you can pick one of the web app ones - for example: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-web-app-sql-database/ - has a SQL database linked to a web app.

The ARM template allows you to do a "no-hands" deployment of the resources and know when they are ready for further action.  You can also deploy from any of the supported continuous deployment options (see the template with a GitHub connection as an example) or you can use ftp/msdeploy after the deployment is successful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy

This is the github example mentioned in previous answer
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-github-deploy